# Incorrect source maps when using Gulp with source maps plugin

Tags: gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I have recently started using `Gulp` as I much prefer the syntax over `Grunt` and whilst I like it for the most part I have noticed when using `Chrome` or any browser for that matter it tells me the incorrect line mappings when looking in the inspector.

It always tells me the correct *file*, however it incorrectly tells me the *line* it is on.

What I have found is it seems to have problems with the `Sass` *nesting*; in that the line number it gives me is the line for where the first parent starts, so for example in the below code:

```
#foo {

    .bar {

    }

}
```

If I am trying to inspect an element that has the `bar` class, it will tell me it's on line `1` rather than `3`.

Here is my `gulpfile.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'js_dev/jquery.js',
        'js_dev/plugins/*.js',
        // We have to set the bootstrap lines separately as some need to go before others
        'js_dev/bootstrap/alert.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/collapse.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/modal.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/tooltip.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/popover.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/tab.js',
        'js_dev/bootstrap/transition.js',
        'js_dev/scripts.js'
    ])
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                'last 4 Chrome versions',
                'last 4 Firefox versions',
                'last 4 Edge versions',
                'last 2 Safari versions',
                'ie >= 10',
                '> 1.49%',
                'not ie <= 9'
            ],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['scss/**/*.scss', 'js_dev/**/*.js'], ['scripts', 'styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'styles']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The weird issue is that having more than one plugins between `gulp-sourcempas` is causing this issue. This is bug and currently I am able to fix is by temporarily removing extra plugins. Here is code which most probably will work

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

I know this is not real solution, because we need all sorts of other plugins, but this is what works to show correct line numbers. You can watch this [issue](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/161) on github to monitor progress in this bug.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but yeah, wouldn't work for me as I know have changed things up a bit and am also creating a minified version which uses 4 plugins between `gulp-sourcemaps`.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out the autoprefixer from between less and source maps write and it shows correct line number now in my case.

```
gulp.src(['css/custom.less'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        // .pipe(autoprefixer({
        //    cascade: false
        // }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'));
```